# CoronaSDK: display object static X (ignoring X impulses/forces) but changing Y

Tags: lua, coronasdk, anchorpoint

I am making a display object stay in one column on the screen in portrait mode with an anchor point such as

```
ball.anchorX = 0.5
```

ball is dynamic.  Is there a way for it to stay in that X plane and so forces and impulses won't affect the `ball.x` value but do affect the `ball.y` value? If the ball hits a corner/ other object it will bounce off at an angle.  I want the ball.x value to remain constant as I have obstacles approach the ball from the right and the ball must jump, thus I don't want to have to deal with X movement, only Y movement.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to re-assign your `ball.x` value in the `enterFrame` event (or your game loop).

For example to make it stay at the coordinate `x = 500`, do:

```
ball.x = 500
```